# Background attribute not working CSS3

Tags: html, css, svg, background

On my site, I am declaring a `.menu` tag. To style it in CSS, I used

```
    .menu {
        background:url('images/menu.svg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
        background-position:center center;
        height:50px;
        width:50px;
        position:absolute;
        top:7px;
        left:7px;
        transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.67,.99,.48,.96);
        z-index:2000;
    }
```

I am expecting `menu.svg` to show up. But it isn't. Why?
PS I have also tried `background-image`.

Comment: check the image path `../images` or `/images`

Comment: The only issue I can figure out is that an issue would be with the path provided. Otherwise, your code seems to be absolutely fine: http://jsfiddle.net/uopse8bu/

Comment: You did check that menu.svg displays when viewed directly didn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the css file and image  are inside in the different folder you must do this code

```
.menu {
    background:url('../images/menu.svg');

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:7px;
    left:7px;
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(.67,.99,.48,.96);
    z-index:2000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The common reason would be that you are not pointing to the correct location of the menu.svg
either because the css and the images are in different locatins or the file name is uncorrect.

i tend to believe that menu.svg is not under the folder with the css file(if this is an external css file).

use Chrome developer tools (F12)

- Change the attributes of the css class in the source tab
- Check the network tab to see the response code of the menu.svg is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing locally (ie. off your filesystem) or are you testing off a real web server?

If the latter, and if you are sure that your URL is correct, check that your web server is returning menu.svg with the correct MIME type (ContentType).  You can check by looking at the Net tab of your browser dev tools (F12).

For SVG the MIME type should be `image/svg+xml`.  If it's not, then you need to adjust the configuration of your web server.